# How to install Raspppoe on Win 8.1 (Hyper-V)?

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v, pppoe

I am trying to install [Raspppoe](http://www.raspppoe.com/) (a PPP over Ethernet implementation for Windows) in Hyper-V. It is unsigned by the manufacturer, so it can't be installed. On a regular PC there is an option to load without a driver signature check that allows installing drivers without one. On Hyper-V in Windows 8.1, there is no such option.

Is there a solution for this, or maybe some better way to implement a PPPoE server in Windows?

Comment: Can you expand your question to better explain what you're trying to do and what the problem is?

Comment: I try to install protocol in ethernet interface settings. It has not signed by manufacturer so it can't be installed. On regular PC there is an option to load without a driver signature check to intall drivers without one. On hyper-v windows 8.1 there is no such option.

Answer (score 0):

Try the beta version, as it has support for Windows x64.  The 64 bit versions of Windows require signed drivers.

> RASPPPOE Version 0.99beta now includes the following NEW features:
>
> - AMD64 support. The **AMD64 version only runs on Windows x64 Editions** and supports AMD's AMD64 as well as Intel's EM64T,
> - Branding of RASPPPoE for Commercial License,
> - Improvements on timing (e.g. for satellite links),
> - Specify Link Speed,
> - A number of minor bugfixes.